# @Html.DisplayFor does not show picture which loaded on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .htaccess

I upload my picture to subdomain ex: `www.admin.domain.com/Pics/1234.jpg` but in main domain, address of pictures shown `www.domain.com/www.admin.domain.com/Pics/1234.jpg`

Here is my view code :

```
 <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => firstItem.FirstImagePath)" alt="thumb">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Url.Content() instead, see below for an example.

```
 <img src= "@Url.Content(modelItem.FirstImagePath)" alt="thumb" />
```